# How to insert text to every .htaccess file under every user (domain) in a centos 7 server?

Tags: linux, command-line, centos7

I would like to add a specific text to each and every users .htaccess under their public_html directory. Server contains more than 500 user accounts. Server is centos 7. Each file resides under /home/xxx-user-name/public_html/.htaccess
Pls suggest a command line for this.

Answer (score 0):

**find** and **sed** is one of the UNIX-ways to achieve that. For example:

```
find /home -name .htaccess  -exec sed -i -e "\$aAuthType Basic\n" {} \;
```